# Accessing a function bound to a var in clojure

Tags: clojure

So if I understand this correctly, when I write:

```
(defn foo [x] (+ (* (- x 3) 2) (- x 3)))
```

`foo` gets bound to:

```
(fn [x] (+ (* (- x 3) 2) (- x 3)))
```

How do I access the function from `foo`? My intention is to change something in the function and return a new function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the function value stored in the Var `foo`, just write `foo`, for example:

```
(def foo2 (comp - foo))
(foo 4) ;;=> 3
(foo2 4) ;;=> -3
```

There is no special deref notation for Vars: just use their name and they get resolved to their bound value.
Functions are not something you change, but you can build functions out of other ones, like above.

Comment: Oh well, maybe I have to rethink my approach. What i wanted to do is something like, (def bar '(+ (* (- x 3) 2) (- x 3))) which enables me to do (list (first bar) (second bar) 1). But with a function.

Comment: Then you don't want the function but an unevaluated expression. Read about macros if you want to do things like this.

Comment: Fernet: I think you're looking for http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.repl-api.html#clojure.repl/source-fn, from there you can (read-string (source-fn 'my-fn-name)) and manipulate the expression. Only works for functions defined in files though. I have no idea why Clojure doesn't retain a function's expression in its metadata - it would be so useful for transforming functions in a functional way.